# What do we call those who discriminate against fat people?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

Homophobia describes dislike or prejudice against homosexual people.

Xenophobia describes an intense or irrational dislike or fear of people from other countries.

What about those who discriminate against fat people? In my country, I hear people discriminate, attack and devalue them all the time.

What do we call them?

Comment: I've seen the word "fatphobia" used; even though it is not correctly formed from a classical perspective, people use it anyway, like calling making cocktails "mixology" or talking about "workaholics".

Comment: I would guess "fatasizers".

Comment: The term I hear most often is the act of expressing that dislike: fat shaming.

Comment: Isn't xenophobia a fear of people altogether?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called:

> **Weight stigma**, also known as **weightism, weight bias**, and **weight-based discrimination**, is discrimination or stereotyping based on one's weight, especially very fat people. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weightism)

***[Weightist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weightist)*** is one who exhibits *weightism*.

**[*Fattism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fattism)** is a synonym of weightism also and ***[fattist](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fattist)*** is one who treats someone unfairly because they are fat. According to [Google Ngram result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weightism%2C%20fattism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweightism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfattism%3B%2Cc0), *fattism* is less common than *weightism*.

*Weightism/Fattism* is a sub-type of ***sizeism*** also:

> **Sizeism** or **size discrimination** is discrimination based on a person's size. Size discrimination usually refers to extremes in physical size, such as very tall or short; extremely thin or fat. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeism)

---

On the other hand, if we follow the same structure of *homophobia* and *xenophobia*, we could come up with ***pachyphobia***.

In Greek, the word for fat/overweight is *παχύς* (pachýs). There are a few instances of [pachyphobia](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pachiphobia&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=YhgzVYKOHPO1sQSX5oC4CA#q=%22pachyphobia%22) on the net also.

We can even come up with ***pachysarkophobia*** which could mean the fear of obese people. In Greek, *παχύσαρκος* (pachýsarkos) means obese. (derived from *pachýs* fat + *sárka* flesh). Surprisingly, I could find a single example on a forum where [this word](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pachysarkiphobia&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=IxczVavRL_OLsQTor4GYBw#q=pachysarkophobia) is used.

---

There is also an obvious coined word ***fatophobia*** and *[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fatophobia)* has the  definition: "Fear of fat people or fat people walking past them."

There is another coined word ***cacomorphobia*** - the fear of fat or obese people is derived from Greek *caco* meaning ugly, *morpho* meaning shape and *phobos* meaning fear or aversion. [[*fearof.net*]](http://www.fearof.net/fear-of-fat-people-phobia-cacomorphobia/)

*[Lipophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipophobicity)* and *[obesophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obesophobia)* can come to your mind but they have different meanings.

Comment: Are *fattists* guilty of *fattism* or *fattistry*? :)

Comment: Apparently, [*fattism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fattism) is a synonym of *weightism*. Wikipedia could have listed as an alternative term.

Comment: *Fattism* seems less common. [Ngram result.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weightism%2C+fattism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweightism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfattism%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I would have thought *pachyphobia* was fear of elephants. ;-)

Comment: @Jim: That is *elephantophobia* :)

Comment: I've heard/read accusations of *fattism*, and people being called *fattists*; it *could* be that it is used more often in the UK and/or in social media. But +1 for *sizeism* and excellent coverage.

Comment: Cacomorphobia (the fear of fat or obese people) "Derived from Greek caco meaning ugly, morpho meaning shape and phobos meaning fear or aversion. Thus, Cacomorphobia stands for the irrational fear of fat people." From http://www.fearof.net/fear-of-fat-people-phobia-cacomorphobia/